# phantomjs getElementsByClass() in evaluate can't get element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

It's take me lots of time to resolve this issues.
below is my phantomjs code

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

page.open("https://www.google.com.hk/",function(status){
    if(status === 'success'){
        var aa = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementsByClassName('ctr-p').length
        })
        console.log(aa)
    }
    phantom.exit(0)
})
```

As you can see, In the evaluate function return value document.getElementsByClassName('ctr-p').length when I copy it to the Chrome Inspect Console  that will print '3', as below image identified:
[image]
But when I execute the phantomjs code, the result is '0'!
[image]

What's wrong with that? please~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google sees PhantomJS' default useragent and thinks it's some kind of an obsolete mobile browser:

[image]

Adding a modern useragent will solve the issue. Also see the following code sample for other suggestions:

```
var page = require('webpage').create()

// Let's pretend we're Chrome 51
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36';

page.open("https://www.google.com.hk/",function(status){
    if(status === 'success'){
        var aa = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementsByClassName('ctr-p').length
        })
        console.log(aa)

        // Make screenshots often to confirm 
        // everything is what you're thinking it is
        page.render("googlehk.jpg");

        phantom.exit() // 0 = success exit code
    }
    else {
        phantom.exit(1); // 1 = error exit code
    }


})
```

> 3

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. I copy all of your code on my Mac, but it also print 0 as above showed. the page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36' only advantage is that it not show some annoying prompt like:
  https://ss1.bdstatic.com/5eN1bjq8AAUYm2zgoY3K/r/www/cache/static/protocol/https/voice/js/voice_1e62c0f.js:23 in support
etc.

Comment: Thanks. What is your PhantomJS version? Could be old.

Comment: I have found the issue and answered my question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I give some advice for beginner of phantomjs. if you want get element via phantomjs on website. you have to check whether your website that be accessed login.
Most of website will login default according your browser cookie. but using phantomjs, it dosen't. The reason is you don't set cookie. That is why my question come here.